# Chrome is retrieving old code, even clearing all history

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I have a web site, which uses external dll code .

The dll is not part of the web site. (It is Dynamics AX 2012 CIL, but I think this no matter).

The web site has dll, that uses that code in Rest technique (I use MCV4 for VS 2010, and Rest API client tool for chrome).

The code run fines, but when I do some changes, the changes don't reflect on the site (I see the old behavior of code).

I clean all of the history in chrome - same problem.

For my own user: When I installed Firefox + Rest tool for Firefox - things work properly for Firefox (with the changes reflect on the site). For Chrome - still I had the problem.

That happened for specific users (other users - doesn't have any problem at all).

So, I presume that's may be some declarations on web.config that uses caches between the server and the browser.

Am I right? How this the caches between the server and the browser is called?

Is that a problem in chrome, or something I need to declare on web.config (or in C#)?

How can I declare that cache will be refreshed only when I uploaded a new code to site (A specific time stamp on web.config, or something like that)?

The code of mine in webapiconfig.cs (it is MCV4 for VS 2010):

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter f;
        config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        f = new FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter();
        f.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        config.Formatters.Add(f);
    }
}
```

What shall I write in C# or in output caching IIS configuration, as on site:
http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-performance-settings/walkthrough-iis-output-caching#05

Thanks :)

Comment: I don't want that end users shall do some intervention that clear their own browser. 
I want something that I can configure on web.config (or in configuration) every time I do change (The cache will be refreshed on client only once when I am doing the change).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the DLL runs on the server, therefore it is the SERVER cache you need to clear, not you browser cache.

you're talking C# so I guess you're using IIS

Click on the server name then go to output caching.
Click Add Cache Rule then type the extensions - .dll

and follow the prompts to disable caching for this extension.

Comment: Thank you. I am using Windows 2012 R2, and IIS and C# indeed. I didn't understand what to do. as explanation on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770547(v=ws.10).aspx -  What shall I choose? Kernel-mode caching or user mode? Where can I choose the dll?

Comment: you can't choose the specific DLL I don't think. but you can avoid caching the dll extension.

Comment: just use file change notification, that should be enough for you. Choose .DLL as the extension. This will clear server cache for all DLL files when they get updated.

Comment: That didn't work (I have a case now - that even on firefox and on chrome, I cannot see the changes).I have Dynamics AX 2012. The code is behind CIL. I don't know whether this is DLL, but it is more complicated by just dll? The site uses a business connector proxy (Declare an app tool that is connected to proxy accoount)

Comment: ... I think there may be solution in web.config or in C#, which may be stronger than adding caching rule, as explained on: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770547(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68028/discussion-between-eitan-and-mre).

Comment: I'm not the expert about IIS, I was merely suggesting you look into this being a server issue. 
More info about IIS7 caching config here:
http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-performance-settings/walkthrough-iis-output-caching#05

Comment: I see that link, but I don't know what shall I write on header, and whether there is cache file - How can I clear it manually. (I presume this is a cashed file that is per web site, per web application, per user, per browser (If I install a new browser, things work fine). I don't know either which extension - I can declare the maximum at first - need to every extension to be refreshed (for changing only), but I didn't see way doing that. Thanks :)